# jQuery cycling through list items with controls

Tags: jquery

I want to create a simple plugin that cycles through list items using two seperate buttons. the list does not have to be an infinite loop it just has to show/hide the right item in the right position depending on what button is clicked.

At first I was thinking of using margins, but I'm not so sure anymore. 
Any suggestions?

http://jsfiddle.net/XEUkK/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up coming up with this solution for anyone that has a similar problem.

```
$('.list > li:first').addClass('active');
    $('.up').click(function(){
     $('.active').next().addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');
     $('.list > li:first').before($('.list > li:last'));
     });

        $('.down').click(function(){
            $('.active').prev().addClass('active').next().removeClass('active');        
            $('.list > li:last').after($('.list > li:first'));
        });
```